# Mixamo: can animations ("without skin") be re-used on any Mixamo rigged model?

Tags: skeletal-animation, mesh

I've discovered Mixamo very recently. I plan to use its auto-rigging capability on all my unrigged characters.

The download option can either include the skin or just obtain the animation.

My understanding is that an animation is "simply" applying a composite timeline where each bone is modified separately.

Am I right to believe that downloading an animation from Mixamo makes it compatible with every Mixam-rigged character? Or am I to download the same animations for each variation in my skeletons (arm length, hip width, neck size, etc.) ?

**Quick heads up: Mixamo**

Mixamo is an auto-rigging tool. For instance, this Blender character will be imported as a .zip (containing my .obj and .mtl)

[image]

You are just expected to place the following colored circles on your humanoid:

[image]

After the auto-rigging completes, you can either download your static, rigged character (as an .fbx) or animate it using one of the many free animations. After applying an animation (one at a time), you can either download the character (mesh) plus its anim or simply the bare skeletal animation.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: For those of us that are unfamiliar with `Mixamo` would you like to explain in 2 sentences what it is used for ? From your description it simply sounds like rigging software ?

Comment: Hi @TomTsagk, indeed - it's an auto-rigging software that adds free animations. See updated topic, I've added pictures. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, each Mixamo character has the same bone structure. So you can use any animation on any character.

Comment: Even if I download an animation with skin?